# Genius Navigator mouse cursor is jumping

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, mouse

I am on Windows 7 32 bit, and I have problems with a Genius Navigator 535 mouse. It is a gaming mouse, thus requiring a USB polling frequency > 125Hz.

I thought that installing a mouse driver for the product should amend the situation but what I get even with driver installed [is this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=7k0iBmhzoFM.).

Comment: So can you please describe the symptoms? Are they exactly like in the video you linked to?

Comment: yes, in spite of not being a mac user :(